# Routing Error passing an ID on a link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

I have the following set of routes in my rails app:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :jobs
end
```

I also have the following two models - job.rb and customer.rb:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

I have the following New method in my jobs_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @job = @customer.jobs.build
end
```

I am trying to pass the customer ID directly to a new job upon creation, as every job should be associated with a customer (no rogue jobs with no customer_id associated).

In order to do that, I have the following link on the customer view page:

```
<%= link_to "Add New Job", new_customer_job_path(@customer) %>
```

When clicked, the ID is passing, but I am getting a no method error as follows:

```
NoMethodError in Jobs#new

undefined method `jobs_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f89899d9030>:0x007f898a7ab0f0>

  <%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
```

So it seems like some conflict with my routes as it does not like my jobs path - anyone know where this is coming from?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for @job` will look for a jobs controller.  Because you've nested it it won't work.

Switch it to

```
<%= form_for([@customer, @job]) do |f| %>
```

Assuming you have a before filter to find the customer in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for[@customer, @job]) do |f| %>
```